# Animation nodes "object attribute input" color is not updating

Tags: animation-nodes, color, shader-nodes

I want to get the color of an object on animation nodes via the "object attribute input" and "color" as attribute.
However, when I change the color of the object, the output of the node remains at the old value (which was white 1,1,1,1 in my example pick below).
Which settings do I need to change to get the color output updated?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong color. The `object.color` attribute refers to the object's *viewport display* color :

[image]

If you want to get the particular value of an input socket of a particular node in the node tree of a particular material, you need to use :

`material.node_tree.nodes.get("Principled BSDF").inputs[0].default_value`

I suggest using an *Expression* node to do it. Example :

[image]

Result :

[image]

Another way to do it, is to link the object viewport color to your principled bsdf. Then you can keep your AN tree :

[image]

Comment: You made my day!!! I am using the Expression node and _"obj.active_material.node_tree.nodes.get("Principled BSDF").inputs[0].default_value"_, and it works like a breeze! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to see it worked :) Have fun